# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow' error in vscode terminal while running fine in wsl

Tags: tensorflow, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed tensorflow using conda in wsl, and now I'm using it through Jupyter notebook and it's working fine. I also write codes in vscode and then run it through wsl using `python3 filename.py` and it works fine too.
the problem is when I try to run the code using the 'running' option of vscode and then I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'` in terminal.
I checked my environments and I only have 'base' environment so the packages should be installed there and I also tried 'conda ...' in vscode terminal and it didn't recognize conda either.
what can be the problem with my vscode?

also I have to say that numpy and matplotlib packages are running fine using vscode itself but tensorflow and some other modules are not identified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new virtual environment in `anaconda` to install `Tensorflow` and can access the `Visual Studio code` from the same virtual environment.

Open `anaconda prompt` and type below code to create virtual environment

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow
conda activate tf
```

install `TensorFlow` in that `"tf"` virtual environment

```
pip install tensorflow
```

launch `VS code` by selecting the same `"tf"` virtual environment in `anaconda navigator`.

Now, type the below code to check if `TensorFlow` installed successfully in `VS code`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

Likewise, you can install other required packages in the same virtual environment.

```
pip install <package-name>
```