# ModuleNotFoundError : import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

Tags: tensorflow, visual-studio-code, modulenotfounderror

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
```

[Error displayed in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV6oc.png)
[output in jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ56r.png)
Despite trying all the possible options, I am not able to fix this error.
I am trying to learn machine learning to create a simple sign language detection system. In my VSCode, the above image is displayed.

Comment: From a cell inside the Jupyter notebook, did you use `%pip install` or `%conda install` to install the package? See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about those magic commands for installing from within modern jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the instructions mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) to install the tensorflow then open the `VS code` in the same virtual environment.

Please check these similar [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72030206/14290681) for your [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72480026/14290681).